# Issue with timer updating Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a recursive function and would like to update the form with the time, number of attempts and what the current attempt for the recursive function. Every second, the form should update. The current methodinvoker doesn't work. The compiler will highlight the line but not continue and it will pop back out.

I already tried placing the function on a separate thread but, it preforms poorly, so I would prefer to keep the function on the main thread.

Any ideas?

```
void bruteForce_DoWork()
{
   doBruteForceEID("", 0, wordlen, temp);
}

void _myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        runTimeSec++;

        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { this.toolStrip.Text = "Running... " + runTimeSec + "s"; }));
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { lblAttackA.Text = Convert.ToString(attackCount); }));
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lblCurAttempt.Text = brute; }));
    }
    else
    {
        runTimeSec++;
        toolStrip.Text = "Running... " + runTimeSec + "s";
        lblAttackA.Text = Convert.ToString(attackCount);
        lblCurAttempt.Text = brute;
    }

}
```

EDIT: Let me explain the program alitte more... Once the user has inputted their password that they would like to check, the following happens after they hit Calculate.
- Runs a dummy recursive algorithm to see how many cycles their machine can do within 5 seconds, then I average them to give a better idea of how many cycles they can do per sec.

```
            back = new Thread(new ThreadStart(testLoop_DoWork)); // Calls the dummy algorithm
            back.Start();

            if (rbtnTest.Checked)
            {
                txtEID.Text = txtUID.Text;
                lblRunCycle.Text = "Calculating...";
                testTimer.Enabled = true;  // Starts the Timer 
            }
```

Once the 5 second timer is up, I check the length, cycles per second, what characters (upper,lower,numbers,symbols), give how long it will take, add the respective char arrays for to create the brute force char array, then I Join() the thread and disable the timer.
I would get roughy 7million cycles per second avg...(remember this number). Also, I am NOT updating to the GUI during this time.. Just running the created thread.

Then if the user wants to run the attack, it does:

```
        attackBack = new Thread(new ThreadStart(bruteForce_DoWork));
        attackBack.Start();

        _myTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Once I start running it on the new thread, it is displaying only about 30,000 cycles per second?? and my timer is only updating every second. What is going on?

Edit: I also just commented out the timer so nothing is updating to the GUI... and the same results occur when the brute force is found (for example the word 'test' should be instant... but it takes 10 seconds to find it...

Comment: If I understand correctly your UI thread is busy doing compute intensive work? What kind of timer do you use, The one in `System.Threading` or in `System.Windows.Forms`? Can you please paste a complete working example, the code above requires to much guessing about the rest of your program.

Comment: Not the problem, but don't duplicate your code. Just pass `_myTimer_Elapsed` to `Invoke`.

Comment: In the first part of the code, yes, the UI was doing the work. But that is due to after I tried placing the intensive work on a separate thread. I posted additional code with the intensive code on a separate thread as well as an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this cannot work.  The Timer.Elapsed event runs on a threadpool thread.  Which means for one that InvokeRequired is always true and doesn't need to be checked.  What can't work is the Invoke() call.  It requires the UI thread to be idle so it can executed the invoked code.

Your UI thread isn't idle, it is executing the expensive code.  This is called deadlock.

You *have* to do this the other way around, have a worker thread execute the expensive code instead of the UI thread.  Which keeps the UI thread responsive, both to update the labels, keep the UI painted and respond to user input.  You said you didn't like doing it this way, it is unclear why you are having a problem with it.  A classic mistake is updating the UI too often, flooding it with invoke requests so it doesn't get around to its regular duties anymore.  A timed update is indeed the solution.  Never update more than 25 times per second, the human eye can't tell the difference if you do it more often than that.

Comment: I have no idea what that's about.  It makes little sense to burn 5 seconds on a perf calculation.  Make it 5 milliseconds so a human doesn't care.  That's still over 10 million cpu cycles.

Comment: Only 5ms doesn't give an accurate reading.. Averaging only 40,000 cycles per second. Even 500ms gives only 780,000. I have tried everything from 5ms to 15s and only around 2-4s is when the cycles are consistent. This measurement is for demonstration to your user on approximately how long it would take to crack the input. And if it practical, it will allow them to actually execute the attack.